# My Opencart shows php warning undefined array key

Tags: opencart

I have a problem with a language extension I recently installed. Now I cannot login in the admin panel and I see these logs:

```
2022-12-30 16:30:17 - PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "" in /var/www/html/opencart/admin-084AQ/controller/startup/language.php on line 21
2022-12-30 16:30:17 - PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/html/opencart/admin-084AQ/controller/startup/language.php on line 21
2022-12-30 16:30:17 - PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "" in /var/www/html/opencart/admin-084AQ/controller/startup/language.php on line 27
```

The language.php is:

```
<?php
namespace Opencart\Admin\Controller\Startup;
class Language extends \Opencart\System\Engine\Controller {
    public function index(): void {
        $language_data = [];

        $this->load->model('localisation/language');

        $results = $this->model_localisation_language->getLanguages();

        foreach ($results as $result) $language_data[$result['code']] = $result;

        // Language not available then use default
        $code = $this->config->get('config_language_admin');

        if (isset($this->request->cookie['language']) && array_key_exists($this->request->cookie['language'], $language_data)) {
            $code = $this->request->cookie['language'];
        }

        // Set the config language_id
        $this->config->set('config_language_id', $language_data[$code]['language_id']);
        $this->config->set('config_language_admin', $code);

        // Language
        $language = new \Opencart\System\Library\Language($code);

        if (!$language_data[$code]['extension']) {
            $language->addPath(DIR_LANGUAGE);
        } else {
            $language->addPath(DIR_EXTENSION . $language_data[$code]['extension'] . '/admin/language/');
        }

        $language->load($code);
        
        $this->registry->set('language', $language);
    }
}
```

Opencart 4.0.1.1
PHP 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Opencart expects the `config_language_admin` value in the key field of the `oc_settings` table. But it is most likely saved as `config_admin_language` there.

So the fix would be to rename `config_admin_language` to `config_language_admin` in the database.